# DB2 subquery not working using IN statement SQLCODE 115

Tags: db2, subquery

I'm trying to execute a query in DB2. But it throws following error:

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-115, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=IN, DRIVER=4.8.86
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -115
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURSH200C1; STMT0001, DRIVER=4.8.86
SQLState:  26501
ErrorCode: -514
```

My query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS ID,
CONCAT(TRIM(TB1.ROW1),CONCAT('_',TRIM(TB1.ROW2))) AS CODE_DESCRIPTION,
CASE
    WHEN TRIM(TB1.ROW1) IN (SELECT T1.ROW1 FROM DB1.TABLE1 T1  WHERE T1.ROW3 = 'TEST')
    THEN 'Valid'
    ELSE 'Invalid'
END,
TB1.* FROM DB1.TABLE1 TB1
WHERE TB1.ROW3 = 'CLASS1';
```

SQLCode 115 means Comparison is invalid. Which is not?

Following is the part of the content.

```
**Row3**    **Row1**                            **Row2**
KSASPREM    SRQ                         0   0   Auto Carry                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          SRQ                 
KSASPREM    SCG                         0   0   BRT Buses                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           SCG                 
KSASPREM    SCE                         0   0   Buses                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               SCE                 
KSASPREM    SRR                         0   0   Buses                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               SRR                 
KSASPREM    SDC                         0   0   Domestic All Risks                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  SDC                 
KSASPREM    SDA                         0   0   Domestic Buildings                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  SDA
```

Task to accomplish:

1. Retrieve all the values from Table1 where Row3 is KSASPREM.
2. The result should contain one extra column 'Valid' value Yes/No if value of Row1 is not in the Values retrieved from Table1 where Row3 is 'TEST'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with so many things, a `JOIN` (here, `LEFT JOIN`) is the answer.  Specifically, we need to put the (slightly modified) subquery as the table reference:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT row1, 'Valid' as valid
           FROM Table1
           WHERE row3 = 'TEST') AS Test
       ON Test.row1 = TB1.row1
```

- `LEFT JOIN` tells the query engine that "rows in this other table aren't required".
- `DISTINCT` says, "for all value combinations in these columns, give me just one row"
- Using a constant value - `'Valid'` - returns that constant value.

... so this gets us a (virtual, temp) table containing unique `row1` entries where `row3 = 'test'`.

Here's the full query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TB1.row1) AS ID,
       TRIM(TB1.ROW1) || '_' || TRIM(TB1.ROW2) AS CODE_DESCRIPTION,
       COALESCE(Test.valid, 'Invalid') AS valid,
       TB1.row3, TB1.row1, TB1.row2
FROM Table1 TB1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT row1, 'Valid' as valid
           FROM Table1
           WHERE row3 = 'TEST') Test
       ON Test.row1 = TB1 .row1
WHERE TB1.ROW3 = 'KSASPREM'
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ce8a/3/0)</kbd>

`COALESCE(...)` returns the first non-null value encountered in the value list.  Since, if there is no `Test` row, `Test.valid` will be null, this outputs `'Invalid'` for `TB1` rows without a corresponding `Test` row.  (Internally it's calling `CASE`, I believe, this just makes it prettier)

Note that:

- I've put an `ORDER BY` into the `OVER` clause, to return (mostly) consistent results.  If you only ever plan on running this once it doesn't matter, but if you need to run it multiple times and get consistent `ID`s, you'll need to use something that won't be shuffled.
- DB2 (and apparently PostgreSQL) support `||` as a concat operator.  It makes reading statements so much easier to understand.
- Never use `SELECT *`, it isn't safe for several reasons.  Always specify which columns you want.

Comment: Spot on :D Thanks a mil Clockwork. Solved my problem.