# How to use 'IN' clause in case statement DB2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

I am getting an error while running similar query like below in IBM DB2 sql:

```
select case 
          when col1 in (select colA from tabl01) then 'xyz' 
          else 'abc' 
       end as colD
from tabl02
```

The error is like

> "Lookup Error - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42625] [IBM][DB2] SQL0582N  A CASE expression in a VALUES clause, IN predicate, GROUP BY clause, or ORDER BY clause cannot include a quantified predicate, an IN predicate using a fullselect, or an EXISTS predicate."

I think the issue is because of using 'in' in my case statement. How can I remove this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DB2 subquery not working using IN statement SQLCODE 115](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626582/db2-subquery-not-working-using-in-statement-sqlcode-115)

Comment: What's the Db2 version and platform?

Comment: Db2 version V11.1 and I am running my query in toad data point version 4.3

Comment: [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=64ba66c5d48396434f0083940a2a9802) query works fine on 11.1. Please, provide a fully reproducible example with such an error.

Comment: My requirement is whenever col1 exists in tabl01 then a set of value should return if not then another set of value should return as colD from tabl02. Can you please suggest a way to get that. There are no matching columns between two tables.

Comment: @HemantKumar Once again: edit you question with the `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT INTO` statements for both tables, and exact query on these tables to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query like this. Should work on most DB2 platforms.

```
select case 
          when exists (select 1 from tabl01 lkup 
                        where lkup.cola = src.col1 
                        fetch first 1 rows only) 
            then 'xyz' 
          else 'abc' 
       end as cold
from tabl02 src
```